# Checking system events for open ended dates

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm building a reliability report of several systems. I'm using power query to prepare the data.

The source data only shows if a failure started or ended in any given day but not if the system was already down (or up) in any other day, so I have to generate that availability data.

I aligned the start and end dates and then marked the dates inside each interval as unavailable. For all other dates I marked them as available.

After that I found some systems that are missing a failure end before another failure starts. In other words, they start a failure and some days later they start another failure (check Heater in example below). That's not possible and I need to remove that first failure start from the data but I'm having trouble figuring out a solution.

Unpaired failure start/end are only allowed in the end/start of the data, not in the middle.

**Example Input:**

| Name | Date | Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Generator | 22/01/2020 |  |
| Generator | 23/01/2020 | End |
| Generator | 24/01/2020 |  |
| Generator | 25/01/2020 | Start |
| Generator | 26/01/2020 |  |
| Generator | 27/01/2020 | End |
| Generator | 28/01/2020 |  |
| Pump | 22/01/2020 |  |
| Pump | 23/01/2020 | Start |
| Pump | 24/01/2020 |  |
| Pump | 25/01/2020 | End |
| Pump | 26/01/2020 |  |
| Pump | 27/01/2020 | Start |
| Pump | 28/01/2020 |  |
| Cooler | 22/01/2020 |  |
| Cooler | 23/01/2020 | End |
| Cooler | 24/01/2020 |  |
| Cooler | 25/01/2020 |  |
| Cooler | 26/01/2020 |  |
| Cooler | 27/01/2020 | Start |
| Cooler | 28/01/2020 |  |
| Heater | 22/01/2020 |  |
| Heater | 23/01/2020 | Start |
| Heater | 24/01/2020 | End |
| Heater | 25/01/2020 | Start |
| Heater | 26/01/2020 |  |
| Heater | 27/01/2020 | Start |
| Heater | 28/01/2020 | End |

**Expected Output:**

| Name | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Generator | 22/01/2020 | Down |
| Generator | 23/01/2020 | Down |
| Generator | 24/01/2020 | Up |
| Generator | 25/01/2020 | Down |
| Generator | 26/01/2020 | Down |
| Generator | 27/01/2020 | Down |
| Generator | 28/01/2020 | Up |
| Pump | 22/01/2020 | Up |
| Pump | 23/01/2020 | Down |
| Pump | 24/01/2020 | Down |
| Pump | 25/01/2020 | Down |
| Pump | 26/01/2020 | Up |
| Pump | 27/01/2020 | Down |
| Pump | 28/01/2020 | Down |
| Cooler | 22/01/2020 | Down |
| Cooler | 23/01/2020 | Down |
| Cooler | 24/01/2020 | Up |
| Cooler | 25/01/2020 | Up |
| Cooler | 26/01/2020 | Up |
| Cooler | 27/01/2020 | Down |
| Cooler | 28/01/2020 | Down |
| Heater | 22/01/2020 | Up |
| Heater | 23/01/2020 | Down |
| Heater | 24/01/2020 | Down |
| Heater | 25/01/2020 | Up |
| Heater | 26/01/2020 | Up |
| Heater | 27/01/2020 | Down |
| Heater | 28/01/2020 | Down |

I've tried looking for solutions online but it is really hard to describe this problem exactly.

*Column based solution*

Improving on [Sam Nseir Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428892/13586205) I got the following query.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("hdIxC8MgEAXg/+IciDWxyV5KOxYyhgxC3dpYxP7/dpEXvBczyud59zjnWd386qNLIapGGdPqU2u00f+DWppCu41e16e80FfL7Uan5GKSV87VB4aj/mNZ/vi+PzRXho7OlFXkyWDJJNlEhgxDtZeY/RLCy/OtgNhKoGJ+kN0nEQDEI8BFiLt3aScEiC8B3pOQUP6t4CIOiMeBj2Xj5Qc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Date = _t, Failure = _t]),
    SystemData = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Failure", type text}}),
    DatesColumnAdded = Table.Group(SystemData, {"Name"}, {{"Dates", each _, type nullable table[Name = nullable text, Date = nullable date, Failure = nullable text]}}),
    Merged = Table.NestedJoin(DatesColumnAdded, {"Name"}, SystemData, {"Name"}, "MergedData", JoinKind.Inner),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merged, "MergedData", {"Date", "Failure"}, {"Date", "Failure"}),
    PreviousFailureRow = Table.AddColumn(Expanded, "PreviousFailureRow", each Table.Max(Table.SelectRows([Dates], (inner)=>inner[Date]<[Date]), "Date")),
    NextFailureRow = Table.AddColumn(PreviousFailureRow, "NextFailureRow", each Table.Min(Table.SelectRows([Dates], (inner)=>inner[Date]>[Date]), "Date")),
    StatusAdded = Table.AddColumn(NextFailureRow, "Status", each
    if [Failure]=null and [PreviousFailureRow]<>null and [PreviousFailureRow][Failure]="End" then "Up" else
    if [Failure]=null and [NextFailureRow]<>null and [NextFailureRow][Failure]="Start" then "Up" else
    if [Failure]="Start" and [NextFailureRow]<>null and [NextFailureRow][Failure]="Start" then "Up" else
    if [Failure]="End" and [NextFailureRow]<>null and [NextFailureRow][Failure]="End" then "Down" else
    "Down", type text),
    OtherColumnsRemoved = Table.SelectColumns(StatusAdded, {"Name", "Date", "Failure", "Status"})
in
    OtherColumnsRemoved
```

Comment: You need to provide sample input  data ( as text not images) desired output and clear direction how to get from input to output

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in PowerQuery.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("hdIxC8MgEAXg/+IciDWxyV5KOxYyhgxC3dpYxP7/dpEXvBczyud59zjnWd386qNLIapGGdPqU2u00f+DWppCu41e16e80FfL7Uan5GKSV87VB4aj/mNZ/vi+PzRXho7OlFXkyWDJJNlEhgxDtZeY/RLCy/OtgNhKoGJ+kN0nEQDEI8BFiLt3aScEiC8B3pOQUP6t4CIOiMeBj2Xj5Qc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Date = _t, Failure = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Failure", type text}}),
    #"Added Status" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Status", each
        let
          pName = [Name],
          pDate = [Date],
          pFailure = if [Failure] <> null and [Failure] <> "" then [Failure] else null,
          pSearch = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Name] = pName and [Failure] <> null and [Failure] <> ""),
          prevFailureRow = Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(pSearch, each [Date] < pDate), "Date"),
          prevFailure = if prevFailureRow = null then null else prevFailureRow[Failure],
          nextFailureRow = Table.Min(Table.SelectRows(pSearch, each [Date] > pDate), "Date"),
          nextFailure = if nextFailureRow = null then null else nextFailureRow[Failure],
          result = 
            if      pFailure = null and prevFailure = "End" then "Up"
            else if pFailure = null and nextFailure = "Start" then "Up"
            else if pFailure = "Start" and nextFailure = "Start" then "Up"
            else "Down"
        in
          result
    ,type text)
in
    #"Added Status"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it worked but my table has half a million lines and it took ages to update. I used the concepts you showed but created columns instead of doing it inside the 'let...in' block to reach the same solution and it updates under a minute now. When I get to the PC later I'll accept your answer and post my changes. Again, thank you very much.